# Query all published promotions in hyris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Is there a way to query all published promotions in hybris along with their qualifying products? After add-to-cart we can always get them using the field `allPromotionResults`. Suppose I want to fetch all the promotions before add to cart, which classes do I need to join.

Query I tried:

```
select * from {AbstractPromotion as ap} where 
({ap.startDate} >= '2019-02-01T00:00:00.000'
 AND {ap.endDate} <='2019-07-30T00:00:00.000' AND {ap.enabled}=1)
```

How do I filter the unpublished ones and how do I get the qualifying products?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know `allPromotionResults` is returning the promotions that were applied on the cart which means that the 
conditions of the Promotions were fulfilled for that particular cart.

The conditions of the Promotion are stored as a Json (i.e **SourceRule#conditions**).
Because of that, in order to get all the published promotions that use at lease one "qualifying  product" condition you can use:

```
select * from {PromotionSourceRule as PSR } where {PSR:status} = ({{select distinct(PK) from {RuleStatus} where {code} = 'PUBLISHED' }}) and {PSR:conditions} like '%y_qualifying_products%'
```

where 8796113010779 is the PK of the Published enum value(Can be found in backoffice-> System -> Types).

Comment: Edited to fetch RuleStatus PK dynamically. But is this the best approach we have to get the active promotions with the qualifying products? In this case conditions are stored as string, so we need to parse the string to get the lists of products.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit. To be honest I do not know any other way